# While sending data in JSON, the date changes to previous day

Tags: sql, json, asp.net-web-api, fiddler, webmethod

Saving the data in one function call, where I am sending the data as 2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z but the fiddler shows the different date in JSON as 2019-01-31T18:30:00.000Z. I am not aware that why it is giving the difference of 5 hrs 30 minutes.

On the local case, date saved in the database is 01-02-2019, while on production environment the previous date is getting saved in the table records.

Thanks in advance. Please help me with the solutions.

Comment: 5h30 is the timezone difference between India time and UTC, do you specify any time zone in your original date/times?

Comment: Nope we are just taking the simple datetime value

Comment: also check the locale / timezone settings in all the components involved in each of your environments - e.g. browser, server computer settings, asp.net culture settings, sql server culture/language settings etc. Maybe there's some difference in setup. Or maybe it's a difference in where the user is sending from in the production environment. hard to say. If you are dealing with users in different timezones, but not handling timezone information in your application / database then you're going to get data quality issues.